# Talking to modem with AT commands on android

Tags: android, at-command

I'm trying to talk to samsung galaxy s2 plus and huawei p1 xl (u9200) modem sending AT commands, but can't get any result. I'm sending commands using adb shell and view logs with logcat.

In samsung when i execute cat `/proc/tty/drivers` i get the following:

```
/dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty
/dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console
/dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system
/dev/vc/0            /dev/vc/0       4       0 system:vtmaster

rfcomm               /dev/rfcomm   216 0-255 serial
g_serial             /dev/ttyGS    237 0-3 serial
serial               /dev/ttyS       4 64-67 serial
pty_slave            /dev/pts      136 0-1048575 pty:slave
pty_master           /dev/ptm      128 0-1048575 pty:master
unknown              /dev/tty        4 1-63 console
```

Looks like i should send commands to `/dev/ttyGS0`,  but it doesn't reply. I've tried the following commands:

```
echo "AT\r" > /dev/ttyGS0
echo "ATD12345678900;\r" > /dev/ttyGS0
```

but nothing happens. Actually, i'm not sure that i have to send commands to this file, but others don't reply too.
I've read [article](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471241) on XDA-developers, but it didn't help.

With Huawei i know which file i should use, but i can't make data call. I can make regular voice call, but i can't execute `AT+CSNS=4`. Just doesn't work. Also i have LG P765, which is based on a similar chipset and on LG i can make data call. Can anyone tell me what should i do?

All devices are rooted.

Comment: Can you upload the code, how are you executing `AT+CSNS=4` command using program ?

Comment: I'm executing it with adb shell. The command is following: echo "AT+CSNS=4" > /dev/xmd-tty0

Comment: Not 100% sure but to execute above command through program you might need to root your device. Using Runtime Class you may achieve your goal.

Comment: All devices are rooted and i'm executing command as a superuser.

Comment: Does the version of echo you are using support the -e option?  It may not be interpreting the \r correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you try to send AT command using the [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program, e.g. instead of redirecting output to the modem device run

```
echo "ATD12345678900;" | atinout - /dev/ttyGS0 -
```

I am guessing, but it could be that the echo command in the adb shell does not interpret `\r` as anything special (that would at least explain no response whatsoever). By using atinout you are guarantied that AT command lines are properly terminated with `\r` and capturing should be simpler and work much more reliably.

Comment: You need to compile it with a suitable [cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), which I believe available through android's [NDK tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_NDK), but I have never done this myself so my knowledge stops here.

Answer (score 0):

please try different ports available to check the results.

in my android its working under /dev/pts/7 port number.

also use different terminal to read and write

Terminal 1 :

```
echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/pts/7
```

Terminal 2 :

```
cat /dev/pts/7
```

also try using executing as a root user.

Comment: This is not executing the AT command it is just outputting a message you put in. clarify that in your answer