# How to run AT commands in Android terminal as root user?

Tags: android, bash, shell, modem, at-command

I have root my Android mobile (Spice MI 270). I want to run AT commands. But whenever I try to run any AT command form shell, it is giving messages as 'AT not found'. My whole purpose of routing is to give AT commands to modem.

How should I proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the program [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) which will allow you to easily send AT commands from the commands line. Example to hang up a call:

```
$ echo ATH | atinout - /dev/ttyACM0 -
ATH
OK
$
```

You need to find the name of the serial device for android (on desktop linux it is typically /dev/ttyACM0 but Android use something different as far as I remember).

Comment: I have used atinout, but I was never sure about name of serial device, so I end up with failure. How to find which tty to use?

Comment: `/dev/ttyGS0` and `/dev/smd0` seems to be common names. But look at the section "Finding the correct serial device for the phone modem" at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471241.

Comment: If that fails, you can watch the questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/17718545/23118 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/16169608/23118 which ask about finding the tty device.

Comment: Which `atinout` binary version should I use with an Android Phone?

Comment: @Azmeer You have to compile one yourself. I am in the process of converting atinout to use autotools to make cross compiling much simpler (in addition to several other changes), but I do not know how far into the future that will be, so for now you are on your own.